# NodeJS MySQL How to query ids, do something with these rows, and then update these rows flag column to 0?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've been cracking my head with this. I'm trying to query rows to move to another table using this query:

```
get_rows_query = 'SELECT * from users WHERE stat=1 LIMIT 1000'
```

Then I want their id's so I'm using this query (I know it's stupid but that's what I have so far):

```
get_ids_query = 'SELECT idusers from users WHERE stat = 1 LIMIT 1000'
```

Then I want to update these rows' flag column to 0 to flag them done:

```
update_stat = 'UPDATE users SET stat = 0 WHERE idusers IN (?)'

mydb.query(this.update_stat, inClause) //inclause holds the ids as an array
```

but the update query is not working, no matter how I try to process the ids I got in the get_ids_query.

Here's some of the bigger picture:

```
class Builder {
get_rows_query = 'SELECT * from users WHERE stat=1 LIMIT 10';
get_ids_query = 'SELECT idusers from users WHERE stat = 1 LIMIT 10';
update_stat = "UPDATE users SET stat = 0 WHERE idusers IN (?)";
mydb
constructor() {
    this.mydb = new Database(config);
}
async run() {
    do {
    var rows = await this.getItems();
    ids = await this.getIds()
    inClause = await Table_Names.strip(ids) // function that strips the values from the object obtained with the query
    await this.writeToMssql(table_arr) // this is irrelevant to my question, happens in another piece of code
    await this.updateToOne()
    table_arr = await this.getItems();
    } while (rows);
}
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry I'm actually only limiting it to split it to batches (it will be 1000 in actual run), so I don't need it in any particular order

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Strawberry my end goal is to copy all of the flagged '1' rows from MySQL DB tables to corresponding MSSQL DB tables on another server (with some conditions). This 'users' table is one of them, I want to write the code for one table and then change it to fit all of them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
mydb.query(this.update_stat, inClause) //inclause holds the ids as an array
```

The `query` method expects an array as second parameter. Each element of an array is a parameter for your query, what you did right now is passed the array of ids to your query, then the first ID in the array of IDs will be passed to the query instead of `?` sign.

To fix that you just need to add an array and put your array into it.

```
mydb.query(this.update_stat, [inClause]) //inclause holds the ids as an array
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, I've actually tried it but still no go. it doesn't throw any error but there's no effect. the other queries work fine, but this one won't do anything, I just don't get what's the problem.